# Custom Log4j logging for Jboss Applications

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j

Log4j 1.2.x, JBoss EAP 6.4, JVM 1.7.x, UNIX (Linux)

We are migrating our J2EE app(s) from weblogic to JBoss 6.4. We want to configure Log4j per application and have gone through some documentations.. without fail. What we would like to achieve is below:

1) Be able to edit log4j.xml for each application outside WAR/EAR of our app.

2) Define log file in above xml away from JBoss installation directory path.

```
JBoss Path: $HOME/sub-dir/[JBossDir]
Logs Path : $HOME/sub-dir/[LogFolder]
```

3) Possibly define JBoss server instance path also away from JBoss Path, like Logs Path above.

4) Be able to use Log4j from the WAR file and not use one that is inbuilt from JBoss.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.